# how can I make sysfs parameter value persist for each reboot?

Tags: linux, udev, initramfs, battery, sysfs

I have to write some sysfs parameter files and each reboot. I wonder if there is a way to automatically set those as early as possible, preferably even during initramfs. Is there canonically way to do this?

I used lsinitramfs to check the modules responsible for that sysfs. They do exist. For example: `asus-wmi.ko`, if I would like to change the `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold`.

**notes**

- this all should happen before / mounted, thus more likely I will need to directly adding files/configurations to initramfs rather than / disk.
- preferably it should happen before `scripts/local-top/cryptroot`

Answer (score 1):

Note that since that specific class you mention is added by the kernel module, no fiddling can happen before the module is loaded.

---

**You can opt for some udev rule** to be added to the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory :

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="asus-nb-wmi", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo [TheValueOfYourchoice] > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT?/charge_control_end_threshold'"
```

Care : You are mentioning **asus-wmi** module. The rule here above applies for the **asus-nb-wmi** module. You probably should adapt.

---

**Or, if under systemd, create a systemd service** under the `/etc/systemd/system` directory :

```
[Unit]
Description=Set the battery charge end threshold
After=multi-user.target
StartLimitBurst=0

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo [TheValueOfYourChoice] > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If you are already clever in systemd services, you'll have notice the tricks ( `Restart=on-failure and StartLimitBurst=0` ) needed to workaround the cases where the service would be launched before the asus module is loaded

And of course, In both cases, change *[TheValueOfYourChoice]* for any valid number.

Comment: systemd does not allow me to set the value during initramfs. /etc does not even mounted at that point. So I doubt udev can help either.

Comment: but maybe I can add some udev rules in initramfs's usr/lib/udev/.

Comment: @Wang Comment#1 : You are correct but please consider the very beginning of my contribution. Strictly nothing is possible as long as the asus module is not loaded since that path just does not exist at boot time.

Comment: since the modules are already inside initramfs, so I am pretty sure the modules are already get probed before / mounted.

Comment: @Wang : Then go for the udev rule. But once again please do recheck the name of the module. I was quite sure about asus-nb-wmi but since you wrote asus-wmi I cannot really tell.

Comment: I am sure it is asus-wmi: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ce888220d5c7a805e0e155302a318d5d23e62950/drivers/platform/x86/asus-wmi.c#L741

Comment: it would be nice if we expose those as module parameter. Maybe will create a pr for this.

Comment: ah, ok in most modern system the initramfs tools such as dracut can already automatically add /etc/udev/rules.d/* into the ramfs.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [sysfsutils](https://github.com/linux-ras/sysfsutils) is for.

It should be packaged for most, if not all, Linux distros.  The Debian package description says:

```
Package: sysfsutils
Version: 2.1.1-3
Installed-Size: 62
Maintainer: Guillem Jover <guillem@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libsysfs2 (>= 2.1.1), lsb-base, pci.ids
Pre-Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.54~)
Description-en: sysfs query tool and boot-time setup
 The sysfs is a virtual file system found in Linux kernels 2.5+ that provides
 a tree of system devices. This package provides the program 'systool' to
 query it, which can be used to list devices by bus, class, and topology.
 .
 In addition this package ships a configuration file /etc/sysfs.conf which
 allows one to conveniently set sysfs attributes at system bootup (via an
 init script).
Description-md5: 07811d91c926da426d94db98052434b1
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: https://github.com/linux-ras/sysfsutils
```

---

BTW, see also `sysctl` and `sysctl.conf` in [procps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps), that provides similar functionality for kernel parameter configuration in `/proc/sys/`.  You almost certainly already have this installed, as it's the package that provides `ps`, `pgrep`, `pkill`, `top`, etc. on Linux.

---

Finally, if you need to set specific modules options whenever a kernel module is loaded, you can use `/etc/modules` and .conf files under `/etc/modprobe.d/`.  e.g. I have the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`:

```
# use minimum 8GB and maxmum of 16GB RAM for ZFS ARC
options zfs zfs_arc_min=8589934592 zfs_arc_max=17179869184
```

Comment: I cannot tell for sysfsutils but I am afraid that the sysctl.conf way would not fit here for that particular purpose since the class does not exist as long as the module is not started.

Comment: @MC68020 yes, I know.  I added sysctl as extra, semi-related info.   sysfsutils is for /sys/, sysctl is for /proc/sys/.   and modprobe.d conf files are for setting module options.   all three of them are relevant to fairly low-level boot-time configuration.

Comment: unfortunately, modinfo does not show any configurable parameter for those modules.

Comment: Not every module has load time options.   sysfsutils is my answer.  The other two things, sysctl, and module options, are extra bonus information on closely related subjects, just for "completeness".